# Cone of a morphism of complexes that are concentrated in degree $0$ and $1$

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-categories, modules, triangulated-categories

Let $R$ be a ring and $f:A\to A'$ and $g:B\to B'$ be morphisms of $R$-modules. Let $h:C_{\bullet}\to C_{\bullet}'$ be a morphism of $R$-module complexes fitting in a morphism of distinguished triangles:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
C_{\bullet} @>>> A[0] @>>> B[0] @>>> C_{\bullet}[1] \\
@VVhV @VVfV @VVgV @VVh[1]V \\
C_{\bullet}' @>>> A'[0] @>>> B'[0] @>>> C_{\bullet}'[1]
\end{CD}$$

From a paper I am reading, the following is used:

> If $f$ and $g$ are injective morphisms, we have a quasi-isomorphism $\operatorname{cone}(h)\cong[\operatorname{coker}(f)\to \operatorname{coker}(g)]$.

It seems that the equivalent general statement is wrong, i.e. if $f$ and $g$ are not assumed to be injective and $A[0]$, $A'[0]$, $B[0]$ and $B'[0]$ are not assumed to be concentrated in degree $0$ anymore (see for instance [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2513848/cones-of-a-morphism-of-distinguished-triangles/2515484#2515484)).

Does anyone have a proof - if true -  of this statement?

Many thanks!

Comment: This is easy to show for the functorial cone (when $f,g$ are injective).  Are you specifically worried about choosing $h$ in a way that disagrees with the functorial cone?

Comment: A priori $h$ is arbitrary here (but still such that it forms a morphism of distinguished triangles). Is this an issue regarding the truth of the statement?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure.  It seems likely that by modifying $h$ you can end up with a non isomorphic cone, but I don't know how to construct a pathological example right now.

Comment: After a small computation, it seems that $\operatorname{cone} h$ do depend on the differential of $C_{\bullet}$ and $C_{\bullet}'$ while $[\operatorname{coker}f\to \operatorname{coker} g]$ do not. Maybe this explains why $h$ cannot be arbitrary?